# QT,QTML How to add image Combobox list

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt Quitck Control 2.0 . I want to add image and text into Combobox list. Image is left , text is rigth. How to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write a custom delegate:

```
delegate: ItemDelegate {
    id: delegatRoot
    width: control.width
    height: 40
    Row {
        Image {
            width: delegateRoot.width / 2
            height: 40
            source: 'my/image/path.png'
        }
        Text {
            text: 'myText'
        }
    }
}
```

As in any view, you can use `model.roleName` to get the values from your `ListModel`.